# How to draw hash marks on lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a simple way to add the equality marks on equal lines (hash marks)? Sure, I could manually draw a small line but it becomes quite tedious when 3+ lines are equal in a figure.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.8]
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I draw a hash mark on this line? Like this:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you show us how you draw the figure without the hash marks? I'm sure you'll then find somebody able to help with the marks.

Comment: How should they look? The simplest would be to place a `sloped` node with text `/` or similar on the line, i.e. `\draw (0,1)--node[sloped]{/} (1,1);`. For more complex marking, the `pic` function was made for this. Finally, there's the [`decoration.markings`](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.markings) library that provides the same functionality (and a bit more) but I don't think you need that if you would allow a slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the `sloped` option together with a label `$|||$` (or however many lines you want. For smaller marks you could use `$\scriptstyle|||$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0)--node[sloped]{$|||$}(2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, very straightforward. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

With this code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[] (-1,0) -- (3,1) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\arrowvert$}; 
        \draw[] (3,1) -- (5,-1) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\Arrowvert$}; 
        \draw[] (5,-1) -- (-1,0) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\times$};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

**ADD**: With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=2pt] (-1,-2)--(2,3) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\arrowvert$};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (2,3)--(5,2) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\Arrowvert$}; 
        \draw[line width=2pt] (5,2)--(2,-3) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\arrowvert$};
        \draw[line width=2pt] (2,-3)--(-1,-2) node[pos=.5,sloped] () {\bfseries $\Arrowvert$};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

You can mark equals sides with the same symbol:

[image]